# Counting 24 rows below a specific row in dataset

Tags: counting

I am attempting to solve this coding issue. I have the dataset below.  The status hour is set based on time in my dataset and then I need to count 24 hours from there to complete an analysis on just those set of hours once they go on status. I am attempting to count 24 hours from the point they go on status. The easiest way is for me to go to the source excel and add the '1' status for the subsequent 24 hours but it is not efficient as I will have many IDs I would have to do this for. So far my attempts count the spots that do not have a status.  Can I please have help either adding 1 to the 23 rows below when status appears or just counting 24 rows with the new variable 'Status hour'.

Here is a few things I have tried from other threads to this point but it is not what I am looking for.

Please ask if I can clarify anything and thank you in advance for any and all help.
Sample data:

```
data Testing;
input ID Date Hour Status;
format date date9.;
datalines;
223257  26-Jul-23   1       
223257  26-Jul-23   2       
223257  26-Jul-23   3       
223257  26-Jul-23   4       
223257  26-Jul-23   5       
223257  26-Jul-23   6       
223257  26-Jul-23   7       
223257  26-Jul-23   8   1   
223257  26-Jul-23   9       
223257  26-Jul-23   10      
223257  26-Jul-23   11      
223257  26-Jul-23   12      
223257  26-Jul-23   13      
223257  26-Jul-23   14      
223257  26-Jul-23   15      
223257  26-Jul-23   16      
223257  26-Jul-23   17      
223257  26-Jul-23   18      
223257  26-Jul-23   19      
223257  26-Jul-23   20      
223257  26-Jul-23   21      
223257  26-Jul-23   22      
223257  26-Jul-23   23      
223257  27-Jul-23   1       
223257  27-Jul-23   2       
223257  27-Jul-23   3       
223257  27-Jul-23   4       
223257  27-Jul-23   5       
223257  27-Jul-23   6       
223257  27-Jul-23   7       
223257  27-Jul-23   8       
223257  27-Jul-23   9       
223257  27-Jul-23   10      
232706  26-Jul-23   1       
232706  26-Jul-23   2       
232706  26-Jul-23   3       
232706  26-Jul-23   4       
232706  26-Jul-23   5       
232706  26-Jul-23   6       
232706  26-Jul-23   7       
232706  26-Jul-23   8       
232706  26-Jul-23   9       
232706  26-Jul-23   10      
232706  26-Jul-23   11      
232706  26-Jul-23   12  1   
232706  26-Jul-23   13      
232706  26-Jul-23   14      
232706  26-Jul-23   15      
232706  26-Jul-23   16      
232706  26-Jul-23   17      
232706  26-Jul-23   18      
232706  26-Jul-23   19      
232706  26-Jul-23   20      
232706  26-Jul-23   21      
232706  26-Jul-23   22      
232706  26-Jul-23   23      
232706  26-Jul-23   24      
232706  27-Jul-23   1       
232706  27-Jul-23   2       
232706  27-Jul-23   3       
232706  27-Jul-23   4       
232706  27-Jul-23   5       
232706  27-Jul-23   6       
232706  27-Jul-23   7       
232706  27-Jul-23   8       
232706  27-Jul-23   9       
232706  27-Jul-23   10      
232706  27-Jul-23   11      
232706  27-Jul-23   12      
232706  27-Jul-23   13      
232706  27-Jul-23   14      

;
run;
```

This has not worked for me as it does not start at the Status when 1 appears.